# discord-oauth and flask (quart) set-cookie failing

Tags: flask, oauth, discord, session-cookies, quart

I have a quart (basically flask) web-app that is doing OAuth2 with discord.  It seems to be working in the cloud, but locally the set-cookie header that appears in the http response after discord authorizes the user is being IGNORED by the browser.

there is an HTTP response with set-cookie.  the next request is the callback uri and it has a different session cookie!  This is a serious problem and I'm completely stumped.  It only seems to be happening on local host?  I've read some about browsers ignoring set-cookie, but I have no domain in the set-cookie field and my path is "/"

```
Response from discord
session=<cookie_A>; Expires=Thu, 08-Oct-2020 19:22:57 GMT; HttpOnly; Path=/

request for callback url
session=<cookie_B>
```

Comment: Could you share the Set-Cookie header in both cases (save for the sensitive value)? Without it I don't think I can help.

Comment: Hey I should have answered. But my issues was using 127.0.0.1 in my browser and then having the discord callback uri be localhost, browser cookies treat that as two separate domains...